# Brute force disc combination lock with minimal number of clicks?

Tags: algorithms

I have a bicycle lock as the one in the image, to which I have forgotten the combination. It has $4$ rotating discs, each containing the digits $0$-$9$, which makes for a total of $10000$ possible combinations.

I want to brute force it (try every single combination until it opens), but I want to limit the wear on the discs. I would quantify the wear in "clicks", where one click is rotating one disc by one digit (so getting disc $3$ from digit $5$ to digit $8$ would take $3$ clicks, and getting from $9$ to $1$ would take $2$ clicks).

The classic approach would be to start at $00000$ and simply use an increment of $1$, as in $0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005, 0006, 0007, 0008, 0009, 0010, 0011, \dots 9999$. However I can see some potential for optimization, since with this method, at certain points I turn multiple discs at a time while only progressing by a single combination. For example, from $0009$ to $0010$ I turn both disc $3$ from $0$ to $1$ and disc $4$ from $9$ to $0$ at the same time.

Unless I'm missing something, this method would result in something like $\frac{10000}{1}+\frac{10000}{10}+\frac{10000}{100}+\frac{10000}{1000}=11110$ clicks for the $10000$ combinations, or a "click efficiency" of $\frac{10000}{11110}\approx90\%$.

Which made me wonder, is it possible to do better than that? As in, use less clicks to still cover all possible combinations? Obviously less than $9999$ clicks is impossible, but might there be a way to do it in $9999$ clicks exactly? Or if not, what could be the lowest possible number?

[image: 4 digit combination lock]

**Bonus:** Can we also distribute the clicks between the discs more evenly? Currently about $90\%$ of clicks happen on disc $4$, which would wear it down much more than the others.

Comment: Instead of going from 9 to 10, you could go to 19, and then 18 through 10, then 20, etc.

Comment: For $n$ (number base) and any $d$ (dimension / number of discs), show that there is a hamiltonian path though $n^d$ (that doesn't require going from $n$ to $0$ even), so we could do so in $n^d$ clicks.  Induction on $d$ works well.

Comment: Or consider a minimal spanning tree on the complete graph  having combinations as vértices and edge weights equal to the Hamming distance between two combinations

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a 10-ary [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).